# nginx does not respect server_name

Tags: nginx

I have two virtual hosts on my nginx server with their respective domain name. One is http only because it’s a static site (siteA), the other is https only (siteB). For siteB I have a permanent redirection from the http access to the https access.

The config for `siteA` is

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name siteA.example.com;
    ...
    location / {
        ...
    }
}
```

The config for `siteB` is

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name siteB.example.com;
    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name siteB.example.com;
    ...
    location / {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I access `https://siteA.example.com` I get back `https://siteB.example.com`. How may I avoid this ?

Do I have to use `listen siteB.example.com:443 ssl;` instead of simply `listen 443 ssl;` ?

I expected that `server_name` specifies the server name to match for the HOST value in the HTTP request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case is one, where a `Host` header is sent, that matches none of the `server_name` directives in the configuration.

Nginx (as well as Apache) will resolve this by answering the request in the context of the `default_server` item which if not given is chosen from the first virtual host read.

If you have different IP addresses for the hosts, you can just chose to filter the `listen` directive, but if you share IPs the canonical way is to create a dedicated `default_server` item with a rewrite rule that will always return a "Host not found" page and a HTTP error, often 404.

Comment: How do you define a default server for https (:443) without providing a certificate ? I use the same IP address for all sites, but they have distinct certificates. When trying to access to https://siteA.exaple.com witha browser, I get a blocking warning that the certificate doesn’t match. But clients that don’t check certificates (e.g. bots) will get through.

Comment: No matter what the experience of the user - this is the way the webserver will handle it (at least nginx and Apache). The idea is: Better a "Host not found" with a warning, than content from a different site with a warning.

Comment: I agree. I already did that for port 80. But for port 443 and https, shouldn’t I specify ssl and provide a certificate ? May I simply add listen 443 beside listen 80 ? Wouldn’t this conflict with the other https servers listening on port 443 ? EDIT: [This](https://serverfault.com/a/578784/11829) answer my question.

Comment: Which is exactly what I suggested, plus a more readable error page.